# I need PHP script which does not register users who has same Username

Tags: php

I need PHP script wich does not register users who has same Username. I write script, it work fine but it register users which have same USERNAME. I want that my script  Check Username  and if it Available continue registration and if it Unavailable Stop registration. I am sorry, my English is ill :d :D   PLZ write this script.

this is my script and plz tell how to edit this

[my script](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=2468043#)

The script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<body>


<?php require_once('Connections/tourname_regcs16.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }


  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);


  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}


$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}


if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO members (team_name, team_member1, team_member2, team_member3, team_member4, team_member5, email, phone_number, emoney, password,win ,defeat ,score , tour_status_complete, tour_status_progress, tour_status_willstart, team_status_payed, team_status_notpayed, team_place_1, team_place_2, team_place_3, team_place_4, team_place_5, team_place_6, team_place_7, team_place_8, team_place_9, team_place_10, team_place_11, team_place_12, team_place_13, team_place_14, team_place_15, team_place_16, team_place_17, team_place_18, team_place_19, team_place_20, team_place_final, `data`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_member1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_member2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_member3'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_member4'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_member5'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['phone_number'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['emoney'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['password'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['win'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['defeat'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['score'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tour_status_complete'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tour_status_progress'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tour_status_willstart'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_status_payed'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_status_notpayed'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_3'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_4'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_5'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_6'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_7'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_8'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_9'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_10'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_11'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_12'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_13'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_14'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_15'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_16'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_17'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_18'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_19'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_20'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['team_place_final'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['data'], "date"));


  mysql_select_db($database_tourname_regcs16, $tourname_regcs16);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $tourname_regcs16) or die(mysql_error());


  $insertGoTo = "cs16_reg_complete.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}








?>
<style type="text/css">
#form1 table tr td p {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>




<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table width="493" align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td width="120" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">გუნდის სახელი:</td>
      <td width="250"><p><input type="text" name="team_name" value="" size="32" /></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">გუნდის წევრი №1:</td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="team_member1" value="" size="32" /></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">გუნდის წევრი №2:</td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="team_member2" value="" size="32" /></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">გუნდის წევრი №3:</td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="team_member3" value="" size="32" /></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">გუნდის წევრი №4:</td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="team_member4" value="" size="32" /></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">გუნდის წევრი №5:</td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="team_member5" value="" size="32" /></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Emoney:</td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="emoney" value="" size="32" /></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">ელ. ფოსტა:</td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="32" /></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">მობ. ნომერი:</td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="phone_number" value="" size="32" /></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">პაროლი:</td>
      <td><p><input type="password" name="password" value="" size="32" /></p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><p><br><input type="submit" value="რეგისტრაცია" /></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="win" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="defeat" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="score" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tour_status_complete" value="Complete" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tour_status_progress" value="In Progress" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tour_status_willstart" value="Is Starting" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_status_payed" value="Payed" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_status_notpayed" value="Not Payed" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_1" value="Round I" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_2" value="Round II" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_3" value="Round III" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_4" value="Round IV" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_5" value="Round V" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_6" value="Round VI" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_7" value="Round VII" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_8" value="Round VIII" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_9" value="Round IX" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_10" value="Round X" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_11" value="Round XI" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_12" value="Round XII" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_13" value="Round XIII" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_14" value="Round XIV" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_15" value="Round XV" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_16" value="Round XVI" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_17" value="Round XVII" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_18" value="Round XVIII" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_19" value="Round XIX" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_20" value="Round XX" />
  <input type="hidden" name="team_place_final" value="Final" />
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php 
echo "Server time: ".date("M d, Y - g:i:s A"); 
?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show some of your work

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You should include your code in the post Gio, not in a RAR file as nobody really knows what to find in that file! Could be a virus for all I know! Help us help you. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are looking for a tutorial as you haven't attempted the question yourself. Assuming you use MySQL, [here's a neat tutorial](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/php/user-registration.html).

In future I'd suggest you show some of your working as this is not a community that does the work for you, we are here to ASSIST you.

Answer (score 1):

fire; php mysql query for **username** ex. `select * from users where username='$username'`. if it returns any row then the username is already assigned otherwise you can register that user.

Answer (score 1):

You need simply on registration stage, when user press registration button, look into the database and try to find user with entered username:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?
```

if record was found then simply display registration error "User with this username already exist" if record not found - create new record in the database users table:

```sql
INSERT INTO users SET username = ?, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it on form submit action in PHP. for example..

```
if(isset($_POST) && (!empty($_POST)){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
   $username_exist_query  = "SELECT * from usertable where username = '".$usernae."' WHERE conditions";
   $username_result = mysql_query($username_exist_query) or die(mysql_error());
   if($username_result){
      if(mysql_num_rows($username_result) == 0){
            //Do Registration operation
     }else{
         echo "Username already exist!";
     }
  }

}
```

hope this example code will be helpful for you.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

at some point, you send AJAX request (i.e. via jQuery) with username string to some simple PHP script, which takes the username, runs SQL query to check if the username already is in DB and returns the result.

Comment: No code? This is what the user asked for.